# Terraform 1.1.7 - Error: Backend configuration changed

Tags: terraform

I have a problem when I try to run Terraform v1.1.7 against Azure.
This is at the first run, and there is no statefile present in the "artifactory" backend.

When I was running with Terraform 0.13, this would have run and at the end, the script would have put the statefile in Nexus and the next run of the pipeline gets the statefile and use it, update it and then put it back to Nexus.

So this was working under terraform 0.13.
What am I doing wrong now?

main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.credentials.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.credentials.tenant_id
  client_id       = var.credentials.client_id
  client_secret   = var.credentials.client_secret
  features {
    key_vault {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
    }
  }
}

...
```

The state is kept in Nexus and the statefile looks like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "artifactory" {
    url      = "https://nexusbox/nexus/repository/"
    repo     = "terraform"
    subpath  = "component/vault"
    username = "theusername"
    password = "somegiberrish"
  }
}


#>/usr/bin/terraform version
Terraform v1.1.7
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.2
```

The problem:

```
#> terraform init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Backend configuration changed
│
│ A change in the backend configuration has been detected, which may require 
 migrating existing state.
│
│ If you wish to attempt automatic migration of the state, use "terraform init - 
 migrate-state".
│ If you wish to store the current configuration with no changes to the state, use 
 "terraform init -reconfigure".
╵
```

The current working directory outlook:

```
total 20 
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 5022 Mar 23 10:14 main.tf 
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 237  Mar 23 10:43 state.tf
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 2303 Mar 23 10:43 terraform.tfvars.json
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 2156 Mar 23 10:14 variables.tf
```

Any ideas, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, has the backend changed?

Comment: There is nothing there. It'll be when terraform finishes and the script uploads the state to nexusbox.
If what you're saying is that the error comes from the fact that there's no state, could you please tell me how can i re-write the plan so the second time when terraform is running, it'll know to use the statefile from nexusbox?

Comment: Is there a Terraform state file in the current directory and if so is it empty?

Comment: No. There's no statefile. The file preset are: main.tf, backend.tf, terraform.tfvars.json, variables.tf

Comment: There will also be a .terraform directory created which will also have details of the state file, see if something has changed there.

Comment: There was and after I've deleted it, the whole things started working again. I'll need to investigate where the weird statefile was coming from.
Thank you all.

Comment: I couldn't replicate locally. Tried with `0.13.6` first with `artifactory` backend, then tried to update statefile with `1.1.7` & `1.1.6`.. worked flawlessly...

Answer (score 7):

I've had this issue too. In my case it went away after I deleted all `.terragrunt-cache` directories in the local copy of the repository and run `terragrunt plan` again.

I'm using:

```
$ terragrunt --version
terragrunt version v0.38.0
$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.2.3
on linux_amd64
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread v2.20.0
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.3.0
```